# Create empty column of StructType in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to add an empty column of StructType to an existing DataFrame.

Tried following:

```
df = df.withColumn("features", typedLit(StructType(Nil)))
```

And:

```
df = df.withColumn("features", lit(new GenericRowWithSchema(Array(), StructType(Nil))))
```

However, in both of the above cases getting an error as unsupported literal type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a crude way, one can use a user-defined function to add a column with empty rows:

```
def addEmptyRowColumn(df: DataFrame, newColumnName: String): DataFrame = {
  val addEmptyRowUdf = udf( () =>
    new GenericRowWithSchema(Array(), StructType(Nil)), StructType(Nil))

  df.withColumn(newColumnName, addEmptyRowUdf())
}

df = addEmptyRowColumn(df, "features")
```

Comment: Though technically this answer is right, as per the spark developer community and spark tuning tips, it is not a good practice to use UDF.
I would suggest to consider the above answer than this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a single liner and without UDF:
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F

```
df.withColumn(newColumnName, F.lit(None).cast(T.StructType()))
```

Comment: Whats F and T ?

Comment: thank you for the headsup. I updated the sample:
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F