# How to create empty struct in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create empty struct column in pyspark. For array this works

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.array([]))
```

but this gives me an error.

```
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.struct())
```

I saw similar question but for scala not pyspark so it doesn't really help me.

Comment: I thing the array is not really empty, it has an empty element. Could you please tell what's your error message? I wonder if something like `df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.lit(None).cast(T.StructType())`would not work

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "empty struct"? A struct that has no field?

Comment: You are probably referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173493/2129801). The same approach also works in Python, but Christophe's way is easier.

Comment: ah yes. What @Christophe did is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the array is not really empty, because it has an empty element.
You should instead consider something like this:

```
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.lit(None).cast(T.StructType())
```

PS: it's a late conversion of my comment into an answer, as it has been proposed - I hope it will help even if it's late after the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

If you know the schema of the struct column, you can use the function `from_json` as follows

```
    struct_schema = StructType([
       StructField('name', StringType(), False),
       StructField('surname', StringType(), False),
    ])

    df = df.withColumn(
      'newCol', F.from_json(psf.lit(""), struct_schema)
    )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).